# Django paths in Windows

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django, so be gentle with me.

I have this code here, in my Settings.py-file:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
        )

print("STATICFILES_DIRS ", STATICFILES_DIRS[0] )
print("STATICFILES_DIRS ", STATICFILES_DIRS )
```

I don't understand the result, which is this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS C:\path\to\static\folder
STATICFILES_DIRS ('C:\\path\\to\\static\\folder',)
```

Why do the double-backslashes appear, when I print the tuple? Is it because it's 'escaping-the-next-character'?

Comment: yes, you got it... it is escaping the next character

Comment: *"I'm learning Django..."*. This question has got nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Xyres - please evaluate your answer. I'm setting this up in my Django-settings.py-file? How else should I address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is a manifold over duplicate question, but:

Python escaping routines. Python uses a backslash as standard escape in string representation. Which is exactly what happens here.

To give some easy (documented) examples:

```
Escape Sequence     Meaning 
\newline            Ignored
\\  Backslash       (\)
\'  Single quote    (')
\"  Double quote    (")
```

You can see the difference through an example like this:

```
>>> spam_eggs = '''spam
... eggs'''
>>> print spam_eggs
spam
eggs
>>> print repr(spam_eggs)
'spam\neggs'
```